# Como agregar cambiar tamaño a un DropDownList en ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, dropdownlist

Saludos estoy trabajando en un proyecto de ASP MVC, en el cual tengo un @Html.DropDownList:

```
Articulo: @Html.DropDownList("buscarArticulo", "Todos")
```

Pues al ser nombre de productos con hasta 100 caracteres pues el el listado tiene un ancho bastante largo,
como puedo indicarle un width ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El DropDownList puede recibir como parámetro un objeto con atributos html.

```
new { 
     style = "width: 100%", // atributo style
     @class = "form-control" // atributo class
    }
```

Ejemplo dropdown con style:

```
@Html.DropDownList("buscarArticulo",null, "Todos", new { style = "width: 100%" })
```

Comment: Saludos Lobos, gracias por responder pero la parte del codigo donde dice "todos" muestra el siguiente error al colocar el new style: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'

Comment: Ya actualicé. Es por la sobrecarga del método, ninguna recibe `string, string, object`. Por eso se agregó null para que coincida con otra sobrecarga `string, IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, string , object`.

Comment: Muchas gracias lobos, funciono !